# Gallery Navigation Broken in Safari Only

Tags: jquery, navigation, focus, gallery

I'm hoping someone can help me out with a strange browser issue I've run into. I have a fairly simple gallery running off of the jQuery Tools library, which I have modified (hacked) to get a parallax effect on the vertical scroll. This is my work-in-progress: http://6ft6design.com/_pt02/

Now I admit to being a total programming noob — all I do is look for the moving parts and bang on them until I get what I want. In this case things were going great: I tested in Firefox, Opera, Chrome, IE, and even Safari's mobile browser. They all work perfectly. Problem is, the desktop version of Safari (Mac v5.0.5) does not, and I can't figure out why. Specifically, the navigation does not seem to be fully implemented. While I can still move vertically through the gallery, the horizontal movement is not being activated (although if you hit the left or right key as the vertical scroll is taking place, it sometimes will move a bit horizontally before freezing).

From what I have gathered it is an issue with the focus command but the nuance is beyond me. Other potential solves from around the internet were moving the script calls to the end of the html document (nope) and changing from $(document).ready to window.onload (also no).

Code below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#stage").scrollable({
        vertical: true,
        speed: 400,
        keyboard: 'static',
        touch: false,
        onSeek: function(event, i) {
            horizontal.eq(i).data("scrollable").focus();
        }
    }).navigator("#main_nav");
    var horizontal = $(".scrollable").scrollable({ 
        circular: false, 
        speed: 400, 
        next: ".scrollable", 
    }).navigator(".sub_nav");
    horizontal.eq(0).data("scrollable").focus();
});

$(function() {
    $("#stageBG").scrollable({
        vertical: true,
        speed: 600,
        touch: false,
        keyboard: 'static',
    }).navigator("#main_nav");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> Specifically, the navigation does not seem to be fully implemented.
>   While I can still move vertically through the gallery, the horizontal
>   movement is not being activated (although if you hit the left or right
>   key as the vertical scroll is taking place, it sometimes will move a
>   bit horizontally before freezing).

1)  In Safari, when I hit the left/right with my mouse, I get a popup message telling me that I **must** use the left/right keyboard arrows.  So your "bug" seems to be exactly how it's "supposed" to work.  It's like some obscure option you neglected to select within jQuery Tools, some jQuery Tools required markup is missing, or yet another issue with jQuery Tools.

2)  Secondly, you're using Flowplayer's jQuery Tools.  IMHO, I'd stay away from it... it's a total piece of junk.  jQuery's tag-line is *"write less, do more"*... jQuery Tools' tag-line should be *"do less, write more... a lot more"*.  With all the great jQuery Scroller plugins out there, I'd find one requiring less markup, more compliant and better supported.  For over a year, jQuery Tools was incompatible with IE9 and over 6 months the developer can't seem to find one single programmer that is willing to come aboard to help keep the project going.  Try something like [Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/) instead.  It will be easier to setup and understand.

[Read this great article](http://marcgrabanski.com/articles/jquery-tools-vs-jquery-ui) and all its comments to understand more about what I'm saying.  It's an older article but the main ideas & gripes are still valid.

Seriously, jQuery Tools is **absolutely nothing like** any other jQuery plugin out there.  It should take a few minutes to get any jQuery plugin installed with a few basic options, where it takes hours upon hours to write all the HTML/CSS markup required to get jQuery Tools even close.  Browsing the Flowplayer forums, there are all kinds of little nagging issues like yours and you see the developer pop in briefly six months ago for the only time in a year.  Do you really want to use a plugin long-term where the developer has publicly stated that his interests are elsewhere?

3)  You have over a hundred HTML Validation Errors including some `<p>` tags left open.

[http://validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://6ft6design.com/_pt02/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Fixing these will help you troubleshoot and keep cross-browser issues to a minimum.  Although they probably have nothing to do with your current issues which, I believe, are caused by, or rooted in, jQuery Tools.

4)  Finally, this one is purely an issue of semantics.  `$(function() { });` is exactly the same as `$(document).ready(function() { });`.  Also, you don't need to duplicate it.  Everything on the page can be wrapped in a **single** DOM ready function ( `$(document).ready(function() { });` )

Edit:

5)  I took another look at your site.  I'm using Safari 4 Mac and now I see your horizontal navigation dots.  It's working fine for me.  If you only have this problem in Safari 5, I'll bet everything I own that this is not a Safari 5 issue, but yet another jQuery Tools bug or incompatibility.

You're also using the latest version of jQuery (1.7.1).  Surely you realize the last stable version of jQuery Tools (1.2.6) was written for jQuery 1.4.2 and officially only supports jQuery 1.6.4.  There were some major changes in jQuery 1.7.  What happens when you downgrade jQuery to version 1.4.2 or 1.6.4?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look in to this. I closed those <p> tags and removed the redundant function call (I'll save all the alt tags for the final version). I hear what you're saying about the Tools library but I'm pretty invested at this point and would hate to ditch my foreground/background effect and have to try and rebuild it using another plugin's logic.Just to clarify, the arrows graphic in the bottom right corner isn't meant to be the means of navigation - it's supposed to remind the user that they could use their keyboard to navigate instead of their mouse. UX fail on my part.

Comment: @user1108120, When I was first learning about jQuery, I invested three full days into jQuery Tools Scrollable and never got it working the way I wanted.  It took me 5 minutes to install a different jQuery slider plugin and an hour to tweak it to my liking.  It was only then that I learned how properly written jQuery plugins are supposed to work and fully understood everything I previously read about jQuery Tools.  Keep throwing good time after bad or just move on?  Food for thought.

Comment: @user1108120, I took another look at your site.  See my edited answer.

Comment: Unfortunately the jQuery downgrade didn't do the trick, although that would have been nice if not an ideal solve. When you navigate horizontally in your version of Safari is the main slide advancing along with the dots or just the dots? If you try it in FF eg, you can see what I mean. Thx again.

Comment: @user1108120, it's working... main slide is moving.  Are you getting any errors in the Safari Developer Console?It seems you only have two options at this point.  Wait for a new version of jQuery Tools or switch to a different plugin.

Comment: Negative, except that it can't find a favicon. Must be something new in Safari 5 that is tripping up Tools. Bummer. Well, live and learn. I posted this issue on the Tools forum as well - I'll let you know if I get a response. I appreciate your time and insight, cheers.

Comment: @user1108120: It's also working fine for me in Safari 5.1.2 Mac so your problem seems to be isolated to Safari Windows.  Good luck at the Flowplayer forums; it's been like a ghost-town over there for a long time.  When the developer does not care enough to help, why should anyone else?  Please come back with any updates and if you find a solution, please post it here as an answer to your question.

Comment: Sorry for the late update, but for the sake of posterity here it is. I did finally find the wrench in the works: I had a swf animation running in one of my slides and for whatever reason it was causing the latest version of Safari to freeze portions of the gallery. Solution: no swfs.

Comment: @user1108120, Yeah, no surprise.  Apple claims the #1 cause of Safari crashes is the Flash plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I did finally find the wrench in the works: I had a swf animation running in one of my slides and for whatever reason it was causing the latest version of Safari to freeze portions of the gallery. Solution: no swfs.